# Linq to Entities Querying a Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a Tag and an Article object with a many-to-many relationship using Entity Framework 4.1. 
I just want to retrieve a list of Articles which have a Tag. However the below code fails:

```
var db = new ArticleContext();
        var tag = db.Tags.Find(tagId);
        var articles= from article in db.Articles
                       where article.Tags.Contains(tag)
                       select article;
```

The error is "Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."
I understand that this is a known issue with EF ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx#RefNonScalarClosures ) but what is the best workaround?

Comment: Is this not accessible via tag.Articles?

Comment: Unfortunately not, EF does not load related objects by default.

Comment: @Judo: You can force it to load related objects using `.Include()` in the original query, or `.Load()` later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var articles= from article in db.Articles
               where article.Tags.Any(tag => tag.Id == tagId)
               select article;
```

Comment: Perfect. I was trying this using Include without success.